# Booleans Values

Tags: python, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Which of the following will be fully evaluated that first option  will be checked inclusive the second option, if the following variables represent the following boolean values

```
a = True
b = False 

not a or b
a and b
a or b
not and b
b and a
b or a
```

I tried applying the booleans principles of and, or, not seems I still can't get it correct am failing. I evaluated the options as follows

```
not a or b **short circuit** 

a and b **full evaluation** 

a or b **short circuit**

not a and b **full evaluation**

b and a **short circuit**

b or a **full evaluation**
```

Comment: It would help to know how you came to these conclusions.

Comment: You swapped the answers for `not a or b` and `not a and b`.

Comment: Replace `a` with `True`, `not a` with `False`, and `b` with `False` as the left-hand operand in each one and think about whether the right-hand operand matters. (You will find that you have reached different conclusions about the pair `False and b` and `False and a`, as well as about the pair `False or b` and `False or a`.)

Comment: The easiest way to confirm your results is to replace `a` and `b` with functions that print something and return `True` or `False`. Then you can see which messages are printed.

Comment: I suspect your error for `not a and b` is due to incorrect understanding of the precedence. It's equivalent to `(not a) and b`, not `not (a and b)` because `not` has higher precedence than `and` and `or`.

Comment: instead of variables `a`, `b` use functions `a()`,`b()` which return `True`, `False` and they also use `print()` to display information - like `print('execute A')` - this way you will see which part was executed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of variables `a = True` `b = False` you could use functions with `print()` to see which function was executed.

```
def a():
    print('a = True')
    return True
    
def b():
    print('b = False')
    return False

print('---')
print('not a or b')
print('result:', (not a()) or b())

print('---')
print('a and b')
print('result:', a() and b() )

print('---')
print('a or b')
print('result:', a() or b())

print('---')
print('not a and b')
print('result:', (not a()) and b())

print('---')
print('b and a')
print('result:', b() and a())

print('---')
print('b or a')
print('result:', b() or a())
```

Result:

```
--
not a or b
a = True
b = False
result: False
---
a and b
a = True
b = False
result: False
---
a or b
a = True
result: True
---
not a and b
a = True
result: False
---
b and a
b = False
result: False
---
b or a
b = False
a = True
result: True
```